# Pandas df to matrix ALWAYS ending up with infinite value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science

I am absolutely stumped. I have a pandas dataframe that I have taken out the NaN and infinite values:

`newdf =d f2.fillna(value=0).replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0)`

Then I turned the target columns in to numpy arrays:

`X = newdf.as_matrix(columns=['emailopens', 'customersupport','emailclicks','formsubmit','pageviews','webvisits'])`

`y = newdf.as_matrix(columns=['purchase'])`

However, when I try to fit these arrays inside of an sklearn KNN classifier,
`clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(4, weights = 'uniform')
model = clf.fit(X, y)`

I get:

```
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-195-f3b09646d9f2> in <module>()
      1 clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(4, weights = 'uniform')
----> 2 model = clf.fit(X, y)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/neighbors/base.py in fit(self, X, y)
    759         """
    760         if not isinstance(X, (KDTree, BallTree)):
--> 761             X, y = check_X_y(X, y, "csr", multi_output=True)
    762 
    763         if y.ndim == 1 or y.ndim == 2 and y.shape[1] == 1:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    519     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite,
    520                     ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
--> 521                     ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    522     if multi_output:
    523         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    405                              % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
    406         if force_all_finite:
--> 407             _assert_all_finite(array)
    408 
    409     shape_repr = _shape_repr(array.shape)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X)
     56             and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
     57         raise ValueError("Input contains NaN, infinity"
---> 58                          " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
     59 
     60 

ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').`
```

Comment: What infinite values? `np.isfinite` is `True` for _finite_ values, not infinite values.

Comment: eff... You are right! However I still get `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').` When I load it into a sklearn classifier

Comment: Are you assigning the result of `df2.fillna().replace(...)` to anything? Note that those methods don't modify `df2` in place (unless you ask them to): they create a new DataFrame. It looks as though you're not doing anything with that DataFrame besides printing it.

Comment: I just assigned them to a variable. Still getting the `ValueError`

Comment: Please update the question to show exactly the sequence of steps you used (preferably not as screenshots).

Comment: What do `np.isfinite(X).all()` and `np.isfinite(y).all()` show? And do you have a full traceback for that `ValueError`?

Comment: `np.isfinite(X).all()` is `False`, `np.isfinite(y).all()` is `True`

Comment: Okay, so now find the nonfinite values in `X` and figure out where they came from. `np.where(~np.isfinite(X))` will show you the locations of the non-finite values in `X`.

Comment: Thanks. How do I drop/replace the nonfinite values in the array?

Comment: What are the values? What's the dtype of the column they occur in?

Comment: `np.where(~np.isfinite(X))`

`(array([      0,       0,       1, ..., 4918675, 4918676, 4918676]),
 array([3, 5, 3, ..., 5, 3, 5]))`

Comment: So that's telling you that there's a bad value in row `0`, column `3`, for example. That would be `newdf.ix[0, 'formsubmit']`. What's that value, and what's its type? Once you know that, you should be able to figure out what you need to do to replace it.

Comment: I found out I had mis-typed one of the headings when creating the original DataFrame. That is what was causing an error which trickled down to this. Thank you for helping me troubleshoot! Everything works now.

Comment: Converting @MarkDickinson's steps to an answer and accepting it by tay_thomp would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Find the values where the infinite values occur:

```
np.where(~np.isfinite(X)) (array([ 0, 0, 1, ..., 4918675, 4918676, 4918676]), array([3, 5, 3, ..., 5, 3, 5]))
```

So that's telling you that there's a bad value in row 0, column 3, for example. That would be `newdf.ix[0, 'formsubmit']`. What's that value, and what's its type? Once you know that, you should be able to figure out what you need to do to replace it.

Credit:
Mark Dickinson